# Probability the range is disjoint

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $f$ and $g$ be randomly chosen (not necessarily distinct) functions from $A$ to $A$. The probability that the range of $f$ and the range of $g$ are disjoint is $\tfrac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m$.

I was thinking we do casework on the size of $f$ and in the end multiply by $2$ (because it could occur for $g$) too (or maybe not).

Case 1: Range of $f$ has one term.

$R = \{a\}$ there are $4$ choices for $a$. That leaves three choices for $b$.

Cases 1.1: Range of $b$ has one term.  Then $P = \frac{12}{\binom{4}{2}} = 2 > 1$

I already made a mistake, why is it greater than $1$?

Comment: Well, let's say the range of f were {1}.  Then the range of g needs to be a non-empty subset of {2,3,4}.  there are 7 of those, out of  15 non-empty subset of A.  Thus the odds that the range of g is disjoint from {1} is $\frac {7}{15}$

Comment: @lulu, wait I am confused. Yes okay Range of $f = \{1\}$. but how do you get there are $7$ of them?

Comment: Note:  I was assuming that each subset is equally likely to be the range of g.  On reflection, this is probably untrue. Depends what you mean by "randomly chosen"  If "randomly chosen" means that the value of g(1) is random, and so on, then the probability that the range of g misses {1} is $\left( \frac 34\right)^4$.

Comment: @lulu, why to the fourth power? I see that: $3/4$ probability that $1 \notin g$. But why $^4$?

Comment: A set of order $n$ has $2^n$ subsets.  Subtract 1 if you want to exclude the empty set.  But I no longer believe that looking at subsets is the right approach.  See my second comment.

Comment: I think I confused the issue with my first comment.  I'll write out a detailed answer and post it below.

Comment: @lulu, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Randomly chosen" isn't clearly defined, but let's take it to mean that we randomly choose the values of $f(1),f(2),f(3), f(4)$ and similarly for $g$.

We'll work case by case, indexed by the size of the range of $f$. I will not complete the calculation, it's a bit messy and I'll leave some of the arithmetic off.

Case I:  Range of $f$ has exactly 1 element.  Now the probability of that occurring is $\left(\frac 14\right)^3$.  Why?  Well, $f(1)$ is whatever it is, then $f(2)=f(1)$ with probability $\frac 14$ and so on.  If we are in this case, the probability that $g(n)≠f(1)$ is $\frac 34$. Hence the probability that $g$ misses the range of $f$ completely is $\left(\frac 34\right)^4$.  Hence case 1 occurs in our count with probability $\left(\frac 14\right)^3$$\left(\frac 34\right)^4$

Case II.  Range of $f$ has exactly 2 elements.  Now, the probability of that occurring is harder to compute.  There are 6 ways to choose a pair of elements out of 4.  Given a choice of two elements, the probability that the range of $f$ is in that pair is $\left(\frac 12\right)^4$.  But then we have to exclude the cases where the range of $f$ is just a single element. As in the first case we see that this means we have to exclude events of probability 2$\left(\frac 14\right)^4$.  Combining all of that, the probability $Range(f)$ has exactly 2 elements is $\frac{3}{2^3} -\frac 3{4^3}\sim .328$  If you are in Case II, the probability that $g(1)$, say, is not in $Range(f)$ is $\frac 12$, hence the probability that $Range(g)$ misses the range of $f$ completely is $\left(\frac 12\right)^4$.  Putting it all together we see that Case II contributes $\left(\frac{3}{2^3} -\frac{3}{4^3}\right)\left(\frac12\right)^4$

Now, it is easier if we consider:

Case IV:  $Range(f)$ has 4 elements. This occurs with probability $\frac{4!}{4^4}$ as there are $4!$ ways for $f$ to just permute the elements of A and there are $4^4$ functions all in all.  In this case, it is impossible for the range of $g$ to miss the range of $f$.

That leaves:

Case III:  $Range(f)$ has exactly 3 elements.  We can compute its probability P by subtraction (that's why we did Case IV out of sequence).  Given that $f$ only misses a single element, the probability that the Range of $g$ misses the range of $f$ is $\left(\frac 14\right)^4$, so case III contributes P*$\left(\frac 14\right)^4$

Combining these cases gives the answer.  Perhaps there is an easier way to do it, but I don't see it!

Comment: (+1) and accept, excellent answer. Follow up question, in case one, isnt it: $(1/4)^4$ instead of $(1/4)^3$ considering $f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)$?

Comment: No, because the first choice is free.  To see it a different way, there are 4 ways to choose the unique range element.  Given that choice the probability that $f$ maps every element in A to that element is $(\frac 14)^4$.  Hence a total probability of 4*$(\frac 14)^4$=$(\frac 14)^3$

Comment: So you do: $P(\text{choose 1 element out of 4}) = 4/4 = 1$ and then $P(f(2) = f(1))....$?

Comment: Sure, though maybe the other way I wrote it out is clearer (4 ways to choose a single element, given that element probability $\frac {1}{4^4}$ that all elements map to it.